# How do I get the type of a "Custom block" entity?

Tags: blocks, 9

I created two custom block types.

> [image: screenshot]

How do I retrieve the type of custom block in `hook_theme_suggestions_block_alter()`?

```php
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if (isset($variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'])) {
    // $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content']->getEntityTypeId() returns 'block_content'. 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if (isset($variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'])) {
    array_splice($suggestions, 1, 0, 'block__bundle__' . $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content']->bundle());
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `bundle()` function

[EntityInterface::bundle](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3Abundle/9.3.x)

This applies to every entity, no matter if node, user or custom content block